# How to add an array of views to a scrollableView

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have created an array, and stored my ImageViews in there, I then try to add it to the scrollableView, but titanium complains that it is an array object being passed into it.

How can I achieve this, thanks

```
} else {

var viewArr = [];


                                var view = Titanium.UI.createImageView({

                            width : 320,

                            height : 310,

                            //top: 10

                        }); 



                            view.image = ImageFactory.imageAsCropped(this.responseData, {

                                width : (width - 1),

                                height : (width - 1),

                                x : 60,

                                y : 0

                            });



                            viewArr.push(view);



                        }



                    }

                }, function(err) {

                    alert('error downloading image');

                });

            }



    //end



    }



}



$.scrollableView.addView(viewArr);
```

Comment: added code, see above

Comment: Please format your code, this is almost impossible to read and incomplete. Moreover it seems to me that your view item will never contain more than one ImageView, as you redeclare the variable with every iteration (if this is within a loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an array of views to a scrollableView you can do one of the following

```
// 1.
$.scrollableView.views = viewArr;

// 2.
$.scrollableView.setViews(viewArr);
```

`addView` is for adding one view at a time.

Further details can be found in the [Appcelerator docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView).

Comment: yep thats how I solved it, turns out the problem was unrelated. Cheers mwfire